# What is a good way to prove the weak form of the Sobolev embedding theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

From Richard Melrose, *From microlocal to global analysis*, Chapter 1, Problem 11.

Suppose $u\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and that
$$
D_{1}D_{2}\cdots D_{n}\mu\in (1+|x|)^{-n-1}L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})
$$
where the derivatives are defined using Problem 10 (Melrose meant weak derivative). Using repeated integration, show that $u$ is necessarily a bounded continuous function. Conclude further that for $u\in S'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, if we have
$$
D^{\alpha}\mu\in (1+|x|)^{-n-1}L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \quad \forall |\alpha|\le k+n,
$$
then $D^{\alpha}\mu$ is bounded and continuous for $|\alpha|\le k$. (This is a weak form of the Sobolev embedding theorem.)

---

I do not really know what is the best way to approach this problem. My efforts at $n=1$ only let me get $\int x^{2}\mu^{2}<\infty$. By Fourier transform we have $F(x\mu)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}F(u)$, and effectively we have $Fu, D(Fu)\in L^{2}$. But this is not sufficient to show that $u$ is bounded and continuous. To do that I need to show that $Fu$ is bounded. So I am looking for a hint as I got stuck for quite a few hours.

I know the proof of the classical Sobolev embedding theorem as well as a proof of the weak Sobolev embedding on the Fourier side. But I have never seen it in this form before. My problem is I do not know how to treat both $u$ without Fourier transform and $(1+|x|)^{2}$ at the same time.

Comment: [Paged 4-5 of these notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~siu/math212b/sobolev_embedding_and_interpolation_inequalities.pdf) may help.

Comment: @Behaviour: This is the standard proof I know. I guess I should try to find a way to get $|Fu|_{1}\le C|Fu|_{W^{0,2}}$, but so far it is not clear to me.

Comment: In one dimension, you just need $f'\in L^1$. Which follows by Cauchy-Schwarz from $\int |f'(x)|=\int |f'(x)|(1+|x|) \cdot (1+|x|)^{-1}\le \dots$. In higher dimensions, a similar CS application gives the integrability of $D_{1}D_{2}\cdots D_{n}u$.

Comment: @Behaviour: Perhaps I am kind of slow, but since we work with weak derivatives, $f$ could still have distontinuties of some kind. If we work with ordinary derivative I think your scheme is fine.

Comment: Elements of $L^2$ are not functions at all. When one says "$u\in L^2$ ... is a bounded continuous function", they actually mean "has a bounded continuous representative".

Comment: @Behaviour: But I suppose any choice of the representative of $f$ could have a dense set of discontinuities, which makes an approximation argument (say, use $C^{\infty}_{c}$ or $S$) difficult. Perhaps I can get around with this in someways by reading the notes you provided.

Comment: One can mollify the function by convolving with a bump $\phi_\epsilon$, work with smooth function, obtain a quantitative bound on its supremum and modulus of continuity, then argue this bound remains preserved as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: @Behaviour: Let me think about it. Thanks!

Comment: @Behaviour: Do you think if there could be a typo? If $n=1$, then your Cauchy-Schwartz scheme does not really work as I have $(1+|x|)^{2}Du\in L^{2}$ instead of $(1+|x|)D\mu$.

Comment: It may have been a typo but it still works. If $(1+|x|)^{2}Du\in L^{2}$, then $(1+|x|) Du\in L^{2}$.

Comment: @Behaviour: I see. Thanks. I have written up a proof based on this.